# alternative to an if else inside a for loop

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop, functional-programming

Currently my code is working properly but I would like to have an alternate version of my code example without the if else. I would like to use functional programming with functions such as `find` but I am a bit stuck with the second loop inside the first loop.

The aim of the code is to **update the array of tasks** when either a task or a subTask when their id matches a given id. The updated task (or subTask) should remain at the same position in the array of tasks (or in the array of subTasks)

To simply things:

```
const idToSearch; let index; let subIndex; 
for (const task of tasks){ 
  if (task.id === idToSearch && stuff to validate task){
     const task = update(task, parameters);
     tasks.splice(index, 1, task);  
  }
  else if (task.hasSubTasks){
     for (const subTask of task.subTasks){
        if (subTask.id = idToSearch && stuff to validate subtask){
           const subTask = update(subTask, parameters);
           task.subTasks.splice(subIndex, 1, subTask);
           tasks.splice(index,1,task);
           return;
        }
        subIndex++;
     }  

 }   
 index++; 
}
```

Could you give me some pointers?

Edit: I just reformulated the question, I was not precise enough.

Edit2: the update function is pure. It takes the task (or subTask) and parameters and returns the updated task / subTask.

Comment: If `tasks` is a normal array, you shouldn't need to use `splice`; the updated `task` will already be in the array. Of course, you should be getting errors because you have `const task` twice (and `const subTask` twice.

Comment: Will the subtasks have unique IDs and only be one level deep max?

Comment: yes, subatasks have a unique Id and they have one level deep max

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this?

```js
const updateById = (id) => {
    let task = tasks.find(t => t.id == id);
    if (task) {
        return update(task);
    }
    task = tasks.map(t => t.subTasks).flat().find(t => t.id == id);
    if (task) {
        return update(task);
    }
}
```

This code uses the `find` function, checking the id against the task updating the first it finds. If it can't find it, it uses the `map` function to return all the subtasks of each (making an array of arrays), then calls `flat()` on it to make it one continuous array before using find as above.

### Edit:

You keep asking about returning or updating the array. You don't need to, as JavaScript objects only exist in one location. To update them in one place updates them everywhere, unless you break the reference to them.

Here is an example where I update one `task` but logging the original tasks array shows the newly updated task.

```js
const tasks = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "one",
    val: 1,
    subtasks: []
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "two",
    val: 2,
    subtasks: []
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: "three",
    val: 3,
    subtasks: [{
      id: 4,
      name: "four",
      val: 4,
    }]
  },
];

const update = (task) => {
  task.val += 10;
}

const updateById = (id) => {
  let task = tasks.find(t => t.id == id);
  if (task) {
    update(task);
  }
  task = tasks.map(t => t.subtasks).flat().find(t => t.id == id);
  if (task) {
    update(task);
  }
}

updateById(4);

// Prints tasks and also shows task id = 4 with a value of 14
console.log(tasks);
```

**Note that the task with an ID of 4 which is updated is modified in the tasks array.**

*If* you are asking something different (which I think you might be) along the lines of:

How can I create a **new array** with the modified data in it, then the code will be almost the same, but we must clone the array at the start of our function.

Please note I have added a `tasks` argument to the function.

```js
const tasks = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "one",
    val: 1,
    subtasks: []
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "two",
    val: 2,
    subtasks: []
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: "three",
    val: 3,
    subtasks: [{
      id: 4,
      name: "four",
      val: 4,
    }]
  },
];

const update = (task) => {
  task.val += 10;
}

const updateById = (tasks, id) => {
  // Perform a deep clone of the array. There are many ways to do this, and much better stackoverflow answers than mine on how they work
  // It is this action that "breaks the reference" to the original array and its objects
  tasks = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(tasks));
  let task = tasks.find(t => t.id == id);
  if (task) {
    update(task);
    return tasks;
  }
  task = tasks.map(t => t.subtasks).flat().find(t => t.id == id);
  if (task) {
    update(task);
    return tasks;
  }
}

const newTasks = updateById(tasks, 4);

console.log({newTasks}, {oldTasks: tasks});
```

In this example, the `newTasks` is updated while leaving the original `tasks` intact.

Comment: Thansk a lot@Djave, I edited a little my question (that's my mistake), the aim is to return the array with the updated task

Comment: The array should contain the updated task after running this, although you don't show your update method

Comment: I just realized I did not respond correctly to your question: the update method takes the task and some external parameters (it is a pure function) , but I did not want to bother people too much with details of implementation

Comment: Hi @Djave, I understand with your solution that you update the task or subTask, but how do you reintegrate them in the array ?

Comment: You shouldn't need to, unless the `update` method clones the task in some way. That said, it is probably as simple as `return task = update(task)`

Comment: Hi @Djave, I need to return an updated array and I had some difficulty with this, that's why I used the splice with the index; and I am looking for an alternative

Comment: @Makoto I have made one final update that hopefully explains what you are asking.

Comment: thanks a lot for your patience !